# Viewing Computers with Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, windows-xp, remote-desktop, remote

I have a few Windows XP machines where the users logon to the domain as "temp1", "temp2", "temp3". Can I use Remote desktop to view their screen using my admin login information? The only way I have found to do this is remote desktop to their computer, and type their username (which locks them out). Is it possible to remote desktop to another user's session using my username and password? Another reason I don't want to use their login information is because I want to limit this to administrators only.

I could use VNC but this is last resort. I want to try to keep the amount of software installed on these PCs to a minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view the screen you need to use Remote Assistance. 
[How to use remote assistance in Windows XP](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/wxprmass.html)

Comment: That requires the user to go through way too many steps. Also they must use email or messenger to get the request to me. This is too many steps and may confuse a normal user. There is no other way to do this?

Comment: Within a domain you can you send it to the computer and you don't need e-mail or messenger. The is the only built-in step into the Operating System.Otherwise something like Dameware Remote Control or something.